# Security group inbound rules wiped out and added 0.0.0.0/0 by eksclusterrole automatically

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-security-group, replicaset

I have deployed AWS EKS 2 node cluster(Version 1.18). It contains some ELBs, microservices and a UI hosted on Kubernetes. ELB's have their own security group. I modify primary replica's security group's inbound rules manually to enable access to db for specific IP's(ex:117.123.111.99/32) on port 27017. However, I have noticed that after couple of days an inbound rule automatically gets added for port 27017 - 0.0.0.0/0 and custom ICMP-IPv4 0.0.0.0/0 for all 3 mongo replica LoadBalancer security groups.

when i see the logs in 'CloudTrail' it is saying that eksclusterrole

```
                "type": "Role",
                "principalId": “blablabla”,
                "arn": "arn:aws:iam::MyAccountId:role/eksclusterrole",
                "accountId": "MyAccountId",
                "userName": "eksclusterrole"
            },
            "webIdFederationData": {},
            "attributes": {
                "mfaAuthenticated": "false",
                "creationDate": “date”
            }
        },
        "invokedBy": "eks.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "eventTime": "date",
    "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
    "awsRegion": "us-east-2”,
    "sourceIPAddress": "eks.amazonaws.com",
    "userAgent": "eks.amazonaws.com",
    "requestParameters": {
        "groupId": "sg-mysecurityid,
        "ipPermissions": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "ipProtocol": "icmp",
                    "fromPort": 3,
                    "toPort": 4,
                    "groups": {},
                    "ipRanges": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "cidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "ipv6Ranges": {},
                    "prefixListIds": {}
                },
                {
                    "ipProtocol": "tcp",
                    "fromPort": 27017,
                    "toPort": 27017,
                    "groups": {},
                    "ipRanges": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "cidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "ipv6Ranges": {},
                    "prefixListIds": {}
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - My question is why the eks cluster role is changing the inbound rules to 0.0.0.0/0 automatically, i faced this several times, i want to know what mistake i have done in EKS. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

From de [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network-load-balancing.html)

Amazon EKS adds one inbound rule to the node's security group for client traffic and one rule for each load balancer subnet in the VPC for health checks for each Network Load Balancer that you create

Can be disable [Docs](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/guide/service/annotations/#lb-scheme)

service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-manage-backend-security-group-rules specifies whether the controller should automatically add the ingress rules to the instance/ENI security group.